# How to run tasks file as a playbook and as an include_file

Tags: ansible

I have a generic tasks, like update a DNS records based on my machine -> server
Which I use it in my playbooks with `include_tasks` like so:

```
- name: (include) Update DNS
  include_tasks: task_update_dns.yml
```

I have many of these "generic tasks" simply acting as a "shared task" in many playbooks.

But in some cases, I just want to run one of these generic tasks on a server, but running the following gives the below error:

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/task_update_dns.yml --limit $myserver

# ERROR
ERROR! 'set_fact' is not a valid attribute for a Play
```

Simply because it's not a "playbook" they are just "tasks"

#### File: playbooks/task_update_dns.yml

```
---
- name: dig mydomain.com
  set_fact:
    my_hosts: '{{ lookup("dig", "mydomain.com").split(",") }}'
  tags: always

- name: Set entries
  blockinfile:
    ....
```

I know I can write a playbook, empty, that only "include" the task file, but I don't want to create a shallow playbook now for each task.

Is there a way to configure the task file in such way that I'll be able to run it for both `include_tasks` and as a "stand alone"/play command line ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use custom tags for those tasks?

Create a playbook with all the tasks

```yaml
---
- name: Update web servers
  hosts: webservers
  remote_user: root

  tasks:
    - name: dig mydomain.com
      set_fact:
        my_hosts: '{{ lookup("dig", "mydomain.com").split(",") }}'
      tags: always

    - name: Set entries
      blockinfile:
      tags:
        - set_entries

    - name: (include) Update DNS
      include_tasks: task_update_dns_2.yml
      tags:
        - dns
...
```

when you need to run only that specific task, you just need to add the `--tag` parameter in the execution with the task name

```bash
ansible-playbook playbooks/task_update_dns.yml --limit $myserver --tag set_entries
```

Comment: if I create a playbook, then i'm unable to `include` them later inside another playbook, and it's a small task that needs to be shared among many other playbooks

Comment: if those tasks are intended to be reused, then they should be included in a `role`

Comment: They are, but sometimes i just want to use it on a server - how can I do it ?
When they are part of a role, the file itself is not a "playbook" so I cannot "play" it arbitrary on a server ...

Comment: you can restrict or filter the execution of tasks with tags, even when they are in roles